# SSIS - Precedence Constraint Editor - Expression

Tags: ssis, dataflow, foreach-loop-container

I created a SSIS package to pick flat files from a folder and import to a SQL database. They have 5 comment files that follow this naming scheme:

`ABS_Comment-name.txt`

I need the text before the hyphen (-).

```
 @[User::FileName] == "ABS_Comment"
```

Note: This expression will be used in the Precedence Constraint Editor in a  For Each Loop Container

Let me know if you need more info

Comment: You can do this, but it might be better suited to use a foreach(file) in a folder with a mask of ABS_Comment*.txt

Comment: FileName will contain the file name as shown (ABS_Comment-name.txt)? No path information?

Comment: I think you are using the term precedence constraint wrong. That's where you are programming an expression on the connecting arrows between objects. I used the term "mask" where you apply this logic in a foreach(file) object.

Answer (score 2):

Creating extra SSIS variables doesn't cost you anything and greatly simplifies debugging.

I would add a new SSIS variable, called `BaseFileName` and the purpose of this is to provide the ability to see the results of your string operations against FileName. You won't be able to inspect it if you build it on the object/precedence constraint.

For your situation, you'll want to take the left most characters and you'll need to find out where the hyphen exists in a string. The `[LEFT][1]` expression, or `[SUBSTRING][1]` will satisfying taking the initial N characters. The `[FINDSTRING][1]` expression is how you will determine the position of your searched for character, the hyphen.

```
LEFT(@[User::FileName, FINDSTRING(@[User::FileName], "-", 1))
```

That expression might be off by one, so inspect the resulting string and add/remove 1 to the results of FINDSTRING as needed.

For folks on SSIS 2005, LEFT didn't exist so the rewrite to SUBSTRING is as follows (with same caveat about checking for off by one)

```
SUBSTRING(@[User::FileName, 1, FINDSTRING(@[User::FileName], "-", 1))
```

At this point, your simplified precedence constraint is

```
@[User::BaseFileName] == "ABS_Comment"
```

Answer (score 1):

Billinkc gave a great answer for how to get that string you are looking for but I think you are trying to run a foreach loop for filenames that start with ABS_Comment:

Here is a foreach loop editor:

[image]

There are two things to set here:

1. Set your folder
2. Set your Files with mask of ABS_Comment*.txt

Then you have to set your filename to a variable:
[image]

And then you need to set the expression on the flat file connection to use your variable.